# Datetime / string format in IOS

Tags: ios, datetime, nsstring

I have a NSString that is a date and time in this code: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS" and I want to habe it like german style: "DD.MM.YYY HH:mm:DD"

How to solve?

Comment: You'll need to use [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html), google has a lot of information on the topic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Example of converting one date string to another format:

NSString *currentDateString = @"04-08-2012 08:16:00";

```
NSLog(@"currentDateString: %@", currentDateString);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"MM-DD-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *currentDate = [dateFormater dateFromString:currentDateString];
NSLog(@"currentDate: %@", currentDate);

[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *convertedDateString = [dateFormater stringFromDate:currentDate];
NSLog(@"convertedDateString: %@", convertedDateString);

[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"DD.MM.yyy HH:mm:DD"];
NSString *germanDateString = [dateFormater stringFromDate:currentDate];
NSLog(@"germanDateString: %@", germanDateString);
```

NSLog output:
currentDateString: 04-08-2012 08:16:00
currentDate: 2012-04-01 12:16:00 +0000
convertedDateString: 2012-04-92 08:16:00
germanDateString: 92.04.2012 08:16:92

Comment: Why is the month changing from 04 to 01?

Comment: Oh, is this fixed, or about to be fixed? Any idea? What do we do to solve this issue

Comment: Don't use `dateFromString` with a leading year, what I did here. Or use NSDateComponents. As to when it will be fixed, this is Apple and dates, kind of like oil and water :-)

Comment: @Zaphs solution: the last Part -> german part must be like this: [dateFormater setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

Comment: If possible use a builtin formatter: `localizedStringFromDate:dateStyle:timeStyle:`, formatted for the current locale.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString* input = @"2012-04-08 13:05:49";

NSString* year  = [input substringWithRange: NSMakeRange( 0, 4)];
NSString* month = [input substringWithRange: NSMakeRange( 5, 2)];
NSString* day   = [input substringWithRange: NSMakeRange( 8, 2)];
NSString* time  = [input substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(11, 8)];

NSString* output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@.%@ %@",day,month,year,time];
```

Comment: It would be much better IMO to parse it and format it rather than just shifting around the characters. Aside from anything else, it will then validate that the value is reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Translate it into an NSDate object using the NSDateFormatter, then use the formatter to export the string. Follow the documentation about dateFromString & stringFromDate.